# jParse not showing XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to use jParse to try and display the content of a XML. This is just a simple demo gotten from the web after I failed to do it using the demo on the website.

Basicly, when running the html page containing the code, it stops at `function start()`. It displays the `('<p>starting...</p>');`, and that's it. I don't think it's a cross domain issue, everything is running from localhost and I do not get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error anymore.

Both Chrome DEV and Firebug don't show any errors. Still the data is not displayed.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>    
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jparse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        function start() {
            jQuery('#jparse-meta').html('<p>starting...</p>');
        }
        function finish() {
            jQuery('#jparse-meta').remove();
            if ($('#ajax-cont').html() == 0) {
                $('#ajax-cont').append('<h4>No entries</h4><p>Pls. check back  later</p>');
            }
        }
        $(function() {
            $('#ajax-cont').jParse({
                ajaxOpts: {url: 'http://localhost/jParse/a.xml'},               
                elementTag: ['company', 'employee', 'turnover'],
                output: ' <div class="feed-entry"><h4>jpet00</a></h4><p><h4>jpet01</a></h4><p><<h4>jpet02</a></h4><p>/div>',
                precallback: start,
                callback: finish
            });
        });
});
    </script>   
    </head>  
        <body>          
            <div id="jparse-meta" style="text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 0  0;">                  
            <p><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/KyleRushBlogPortfolio">Click  here</a> to see the kylerush.net blog RSS feed.</p>          
            </div><!--/#jparse-meta-->          
            <div id="ajax-cont"></div><!--/#demo-cont-->   
        </body>  
    </html>
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<company> 
        <employee id="001" >John</employee> 
        <turnover> 
                <year id="2000">100,000</year> 
                <year id="2001">140,000</year> 
                <year id="2002">200,000</year> 
        </turnover> 
</company>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hard to help without seeing xml. Inspect request itself in console to see if request is being made and getting valid xml returned

Comment: I guess that would've come in handy yeah. Edited the post with XML. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so it seems I have a cross domain issue. Just upload it to my website and it seems to get passed the function start() this time. Although it is still not displaying the XML data, it returns the function finished() value.

Comment: so xml is on different domain than page? If it is, see if API has a jsonp ouput...or json with CORS enabled, other wise will need a proxy server ( your server or 3rd party service like Yahoo YQL) to pull the data

Comment: I was running the script and XML file from localhost. Forgive me for my noobishness, but if I'm trying to load a xml, why would I use a jsonp output?

Comment: would need that instead of xml for cross domain.

Comment: Yeah okay. The problem is that from this demo script I have to get data from an XML that is generated by one of our company's applications. I don't think they'd like it if I where to ask to alter the application to output json.

Comment: still not clear if it is cross domain or not

Comment: Sorry, it was cross domain, but not anymore. The script is returning the function finish() value. It is not parsing the xml data.